# How do I disable specific markers in Ace Editor?

Tags: angular-ui, ace-editor

I am using ace-editor with the angular-ui-ace directive in my angular project. I need to remove specific markers (such as 'missing !DOCTYPE) from my session. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/html_worker.js#L40. you can set error type for errors you want to ignore to "none", or even add an api similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/css_worker.js#L61 to customize disabled errors.

Comment: Would this require modifying the source code in those files? Isn't thre a way I can hook in to the API? Set options of the **editor** object or **editSession** object?

Comment: As you can see from the links above, there isn't an api yet. It would require a very small modification to the source files, which you can send as a pull request to Ace.